# Requests Sessions.get Receives a Slightly Different HTML

Tags: html, session, web-scraping, python-requests, form-data

I am attempting to Web Scrape a site that requires a log in. I am successfully in the website with a login, but when I go to access a page, the html is different than what the actual html is.  Please look at my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
# create a session
session = requests.Session()

datas=(***a dictionary that works fine.  Log in information is stored here)
session.post('https://www.example.com/Default.aspx? 
ReturnUrl=%2faces%2findex.aspx',
         data=datas)
r = session.get('http://www.example.com/parts.aspx? 
pn=45')
print(r.url)
>>>>'http://www.example.com/parts.aspx? 
pn=45'
print(r.status_code)
>>>>200

page_soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,'html.parser')
containers=page_soup.findAll('div',{'class':'partbox'})
print(containers)
>>>>[]
```

When I compare the html from page_soup and r.text to the actual html on the site, they are missing some key features. Any Suggestions?

Here is the sessions documentation:
http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/api/

Comment: You didn't pass cookies from first request to second

Comment: How would I do that? I also thought that sessions carry over cookies? Please post as an answer and I will vote up! :D

Comment: Do yo mean by "actual html on the site" the HTML displayed in a browser? If so it is probably rendered with JavaScript, try using Selenium or some other technology  to render the JavaScript generated code. Requests will not render HTML with JavaScript.

Comment: Okay.  Does selenium have sessions?  Or something similar?  I need to have the credentials to log in first.  Also, see some of the comments on the post below.  The data I want shows up when I inspect an element but Not when I view page source.

Comment: Selenium uses a browser but you can run it headless, it will use cookies for a login see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54708375/element-not-visible-despite-availability-in-document-in-python-selenium/54728114#54728114 you could use PyQT instead of selenium see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54589304/how-to-scrape-data-using-pyqt5/54660566#54660566 or requests-html https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests-html

Comment: Calling the json object url worked below.  I had to find the dynamic objects url.   Thanks for your help.

Comment: @JaSON Another one of my URLs is https://www.example.com/ws/exampleJSON.aspx.  This has information I need but is a static url. (compared to my other url that has an attribute lookup. ) Do you have any suggestions on accessing information from that URL?

Comment: You probably need to pass `params`/`data` with required key-value pairs to your request